# How to set custom tag on directive in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to set the custom tag to directive so that the HTML like this

```
<directive tag="aside"></directive>
```

will be compiled to one like this:

```
<aside>...</aside>
```

?

Comment: Use replace true option in the directive. So that the directive is replaced and just template whatever you want would be returned.

Comment: I believe `replace: true` is deprecated because of problems it causes with scopes, why not use `<aside data-directive></aside>`?